# Getting Simple-TLV from smart card T and V Buffers

Tags: cryptography

I'm reading a PKCS certificate object from a java smart card that returns the certificate data in two separate buffers. One for the Tag & lengths, and another for the Values. (i.e a T-BUffer and a V-Buffer). (ASN.1 encoded)

The buffer with TL Values looks like..

06 00 15 01 72 27 00 00 80 00 FE 02 06 00 15 01 69 3F 06 00 15 01 68 FF 01 01 06 00 15 01 67 DD 06 00 15 01 DC 0B 06 00 15 01 66 FF 45 04 00 FF 20 02 C8 25 00 FF 20 02 DC 05 00 00 90 00 FE 05 07 00 15 01 72 27 07 00 15 01 69 39 07 00 15 01 68 FF 01 01 08 00 15 01 72 27 08 00 15 01 69 3A 08 00 15 01 68 FF 01 01 07 00 15 01 67 ED 07 00 15 01 DC 0B 07 00 15 01 66 FF 60 04 08 00 15 01 67 ED 08 00 15 01 DC 0B 08 00 15 01 66 FF

The Value buffer is 5277 bytes long and looks like....

00 01 01 33 39 42 43 37 39 33 42 2D 42 36 32 33 2D 34 33 33 38 2D 42 39 35 31 2D 42 45 42 43 33 34 35 38 35 37 31 44 00 01 01 78 9C 53 62 64 60 60 66 60 60 60 64 60 64 02 32 45 80 CC B6 FF DF 9E 6C EE DF B8 F8 E0 71 D7 CC 73 35 AE 01 AE B2 76 35 2C 8C 20 25 40 C0 06 63 28 02 49 16 10 83 83 81 01 00 EC 33 0B A2 00 DF 07 9F F5 B5 E7 D1 F3 1F 98 41 F2 9A 39 B3 6E 7C 34 4F CB E1 C1 E7 F4 69 17 63 5E CD B8 6C 10 14 8D 6A 4B 32 B0 90 27 22 44 97 A3 E7 1B 63 75 D5 F2 22 E7 07 22 B3 7F 01 FD 1E 3B BB 66 85 0B 48 68 DF CC 66 11 86 E9 D7 77 1A 31 2E 7D AB BF 89 4C 18 AF 74 B5 B5 5F 9D 4D F8 8C 84 03 13 12 10 37 E0 9E C5 E6 82 69 B2...

I'm trying to combine the TL and Vs back into a single buffer, but haven't been able to accomplish that in such a way that is valid ASN.1 and I always seem to run out of tags before I get to the end of the values.  Finally, the fist tag indicates an Object Identifier of zero length which doesn't seem to make a lot of sense either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I've read many specs. and kind find the ansswer

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand everything either about how these T and V buffers work, but I can find tags in your T-buffer and this should help you.

You wrote: *"Finally, the fist tag indicates an Object Identifier of zero length which doesn't seem to make a lot of sense either."*

You are right! The first tag is **NOT** 0x06 with length 0x00.

- In your T-buffer, the 1st tag is 0x72 with length 0x27 - I think it is the MSCUID as per NIST IR 6887
- The 2nd tag is 0x69
- 3rd tag is 0x68 (maybe the public key, maybe byte-inverted)
- 4th tag is 0x67
- 5th tag is 0xDC (maybe the PKI AID)
- 6th tag is 0x66
- etc...

Recognize the pattern? Every tag is preceded by 0_ 00 15 01 in your T-buffer. On a specific card I saw, it was 00 00 14 01 that came before a tag.

Unfortunately, I don't know what these 4 bytes mean and I also don't understand what's the value after the tag length in the T-buffer, should you need it.

Hoping this was valuable info to get you started. Cheers,

Amé

Comment: That will be a big help.  I had seen the pattern but was focusing too much on the 06 00 15 01.  The data should contain three certificates and I did notice the pattern 06 00 15 01 but also 07 00 15 01 and 08 00 15 01.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote: *"The data should contain three certificates and I did notice the pattern 06 00 15 01 but also 07 00 15 01 and 08 00 15 01."*

Interesting observation. It is very possible that each certificate is tagged **0x66**.

Also, I noticed in your **V-buffer** that your second object starts with **78 9C**: this is the header for a ***Zlib** compressed file. You might find this header elsewhere in your V-buffer (e.g. for the certs. too) and you will require to decompress first. Lot's of fun waiting for you before you get to a valid ASN.1 :-)

Good luck!

Amé

*http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib
*http://zlib.net/

Comment: I thought that the zLib header was 1F, 8B?